# Page returns 404 error on submit using angular grid and asp.mvc

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

When I click submit button, I am getting a 404 error, page cannot be found.

I am using angular-ui-grid with ASP.MVC to return a list of pdfs from a Sql Server database. On the page's initial load, the grid is populated with all the pdfs and are paginated. I have added some input fields to the page so that after the initial load, you can then search by name and date range. When the button is clicked, the page returns a 404 error, cannot be found.

**View**

```
@model WSCWebsite.Models.SC_Opinions_Search_Result

@using (Html.BeginForm("Opinions", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", @id = "searchForm"}))
{
<p>Enter search information into one or more of the fields below.</p>

<p>Using more than one field will result in a more narrow search.</p>

<p>Opinions and orders published prior to 2006 are not available in this search.</p>
<div class="well" ng-controller="OpinionDefaultData">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Start Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" ng-model="StartDate" class="datefield" />
            <span style="padding: 0 0 0 3px">example: 2/27/2006</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">End Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">

            <input type="text" ng-model="EndDate" class="datefield" />
            <span style="padding: 0 0 0 3px">example: 12/27/2014</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Appellant</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Appellant" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Appellee</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Appellee" />
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Docket Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DocketNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @style="display:inline-block; width:220px" })
                <span style="padding: 0 0 0 3px">example: 12/27/2014</span>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="button" value="Clear Form" onclick="history.go(0)" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button ng-click="SearchOpinions()" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**MVC Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetOpinions(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate, string Appellant, string Appellee, string DocketNumber)
    {
        if (EndDate != null)
        {
            EndDate = EndDate.Value.AddHours(23);
        }
        OpinionEntities dbContext = new WSCWebsite.Models.OpinionEntities();
        var lst = dbContext.SC_Opinions_Search(DocketNumber,Appellant, Appellee, StartDate, EndDate, 200).ToList();

        return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Angular Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('WSCWebSite', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

app.controller("OpinionDefaultData", function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.StartDate = "";
$scope.EndDate = "";
$scope.Appellant = "";
$scope.Appellee = "";
$scope.DocketNumber = "";

$scope.SearchOpinions = function () {
    $scope.Opinions = []; //declare an empty array
    $http.get("/Home/GetOpinions", {
        params: {
            StartDate: $scope.StartDate,
            EndDate: $scope.EndDate,
            Appellant: $scope.Appellant,
            Appellee: $scope.Appellee,
            DocketNumber: $scope.DocketNumber
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.Opinions = response;
    });
    }
});

app.controller('OpinionData', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.Opinions = []; //declare an empty array
    $http.get("/Home/GetOpinions", {
        params: {
            StartDate: $scope.StartDate
            , EndDate: $scope.EndDate
            , Appellant: $scope.Appellant
            , Appellee: $scope.Appellee
            , DocketNumber: $scope.DocketNumber
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.Opinions = response;  //ajax request to fetch data into $scope.data
    });
});
```

Comment: Are there any Errors on F12? Also, when you submit is your controller being hit? (put a break point in your controllers post method and see if it hits it) :)

Answer (score 2):

your form is posting here,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Opinions", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", @id = "searchForm"}))
{
}
```

look here you have passed Opinions, as action but your action name is GetOpinions()

look on it, maybe it will help you..

Comment: I removed the Html.BeginForm extension and replaced it with just html <form> tag. I am able to see the data passed back to the MVC controller, but the View is not refreshing to show the list of pdfs that are returned.

Comment: Bharat, I think you are correct that this is something small. What "proper data" can I provide you?

Comment: drew, actully it's midnight over here and i am just shutting down my laptop,

Comment: i will ping you tommorow morning.

Comment: soory, drew i just missed to ping you, do you have still those issues or it's fixed?

Comment: I'm still stuck on this problem. I've tried using the ui-grid instead of ng-grid, and both aren't populating data. There doesn't seem to be any postings of people doing this type of thing... which is weird, I thought it would quite common.

Comment: Drew, update your question with your latest problems, so that i can debugg it, if you can provide fiddle it's better..